# Refresh the value of a jQuery variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am loading a php page with this ajax call. Works great the first time, but I want to reload (the user can attempt multiple answers). However, on the second load the variable theAnswer retains the value of the first attempt.

```
$('body').on("click", "#answer-submit", function() {
    var theAnswer = $('#challenge-answer').val();
    //alert(theAnswer);
    $.ajax({    
    type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/answer.php",
        data: { answer : theAnswer },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){
            if(parseInt(msg)!=0) {
                $('#answer').html(msg);
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id=question-form>
    <input type=text name=answer id=challenge-answer class=clue-input /><br />
    <button id=answer-submit>GO</button>
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked the browser console? Might be dying on some error.

Comment: did you try logging requests on server side? is server side getting what you expected on second try?

Comment: @Nordenheim nothing helpful from the console.

Comment: You mentioned "the user can attempt multiple answers" ? Are there multiple answer text field on the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first attempt does another `#challenge-answer` get added to the DOM?  If so, your selector would keep grabbing the first one.  In this example I added `console.log($('[id="challenge-answer"]'));` so each time after GO is clicked you can see if there is more than one or not.

**http://jsfiddle.net/L4h4LLL4/4/**

HTML:

```
<div id="fiddleBody">
  <div id=question-form>
    <input type=text name=answer id=challenge-answer class=clue-input /><br />
    <button id=answer-submit>GO</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#fiddleBody').on("click", "#answer-submit", function() {
    console.log($('[id="challenge-answer"]'));
    var theAnswer = $('#challenge-answer').val();
    alert(theAnswer);
    /*
    $.ajax({    
    type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/answer.php",
        data: { answer : theAnswer },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){
            if(parseInt(msg)!=0) {
                $('#answer').html(msg);
            }
        }
    });
    */
});
```

Comment: Pretty much like you have it. I added the html to the original question. BTW, this probably doesn't matter, but the same html is loaded first from one php file, where the original answer is submitted, and then I use a second page (answer.php) to handle whether the answer is correct and offer the answer form again.

Comment: If you are offering the answer form again without removing the first one then you probably have multiple `challenge-answer`'s on your page (maybe on top of one another).  In the updated fiddle, if you look at the console you'll be able to see how many there are each time you click GO.  Exactly how are you "offering the answer form again"?

Comment: So from your update I gather that I should create a second function for the second page and use a new id for the input text. However, I will have the same problem on a third submittal, right?

Comment: There is a lot of code I'm not seeing so it's hard to tell.  But no, if I were doing it, after the response came back, I would just blank out the answer field so it could be used again and not add an entirely new field to the DOM (if that is in fact what you are doing).  Did you verify that a new field is added each time you click GO?

Comment: I get it. It's because I have hidden the results  of the first php file. They are still in the DOM. So I need to use .remove() instead of hiding the div.

Comment: More than likely yes.  If you put the `console.log` line in my answer into your code then each time you click GO you will probably see a new array element added.  Each array element is a challenge-answer input field with the same ID.  And you code will keep grabbing only the first one.  Better to just reuse one field if you can.  You could change your selector to grab the value of the last challenge-answer field, that would work, but its bad to keep adding things to the DOM that will never be used again and not removing them.

Comment: Boom. That was it. Thanks for helping me get to the bottom of it.

Comment: No problem.  Rock on.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you do apply the onclick directly on your button not on the body

```
var button = $(#answer-submit);
button.onclick(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var chanswer= $('#challenge-answer').val();
    $.ajax({    
         type: "POST",
         url: "ajax/answer.php",
         data: { answer : theAnswer },
         dataType: "html",
         success: function(msg){
         if(parseInt(msg)!=0) {
            $('#answer').html(msg);
        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks. I have to apply it to body because the html is added to the DOM after the page load. Just the clic() function won't find it.

Comment: I tried adding preventDefault() but this did not change the result.

Comment: the preventDefault is called just to block the default action which is for the common cases the page reload if you can give us  a piece of your html code I think it will be more helpful

Comment: I've added the html to the original. See the answer to gfrobenius for another detail.